# How to integrate LISA with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ca-lisa

I am working on LISA tool for service virtualization to web services, and I want to integrate it with jenkins.Is there any plugin available.If not then how can integrate these.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Computer Associate LISA integration with Jenkins you can follow the instructions contained in [CA LISA Release Automation - Automation Studio Plugin for Hudson/Jenkins](http://downloads2.ca.com/restore/dir07/INS07112938E.pdf), available on CA site.

Pay particular attention to page 10 where it is stated how to install the  plugin installation file for Automation Studio `jenkins-asap-plugin.hpi`.

Comment: Any idea why the dbconnect to informix fails from the jenkins and works via my local lisa7 UI